# Excel VBA code delete rows based on calculated number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When dealing with my datasets, I assign every row a random number using =RAND(). I then filter the randomly generated numbers by smallest to largest. From here, I only want to keep 20% of the rows with the smallest random numbers for auditing purposes. I then use functions to add the number of rows without headers, calculate 20%, and round up to the nearest whole number and add 1. How can write a macro that will read the rounded whole number + 1, select the row, and delete everything beneath it?

For example, say I have 100 rows underneath my header. 20% is 20, + 1 is 21. How could I write in VBA to read the calculated number 21 and then select row number 21?

Comment: Apologies if this is too vague or if I could help clarify the wording. I'm new to VBA and learning how to code through small projects at work.

Essentially, I'm just attempting to have Basic read the results of a multiplication equation, go to the row based on that number, and delete all of the rows underneath it. Please let me know if I can clarify it any more.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding regarding selection, you can try this.

```
Sub Random()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
    With Sheet1
        i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        i = i * 0.2     'to compute 20%
        i = i + 1       'additional 1 for last row selection
        j = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & i & ":A" & j).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope I understand your question correctly.